# Constructor for a structure with weak reference to its owner

Tags: rust

Trying to implement a data structure where many "things" can be owned by an "owner", while each "thing" should know who its owner is. As far as I understand it can be achieved by having a Weak reference to the owner in each "thing". The question I cannot figure out how to implement the constructor (`new`) function for these structures. Here is a simplified structure of what I am trying to do:

```
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

struct Owner {
    thing1: Thing,
    thing2: Thing,
}

impl Owner {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            thing1: Thing::new(???),   // 1
            thing2: Thing::new(???),   // 1
        }
    }
}

struct Thing {
    owner: Weak<Owner>,
    value: u32,
}

impl Thing {
    fn new(owner: ???) -> Self {      // 2
        Self {
            owner: Weak::clone(???),  // 2
            value: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

So here I can't figure out two things:

1. When constructing Owner - how to pass itself as a parameter to the constructor of "things" ?
2. When constructing the Thing - how exactly create the reference to the owner?

Perhaps my approach is completely wrong, in this case please suggest the right one.

**Update:**
A more concrete example of a use-case for such a structure:
Consider an electronic circuit simulation, where each "thing" is a pin of an electronic component, which is the "owner". So each time the value of a pin is externally changed, it should trigger the owner component, which in turn will change the other connector values.

Comment: While there are certainly situations where this kind of double reference is necessary, a lot of times it can be refactored into a neater interface that avoids it. The problem with a double reference is that the two values are effectively one value now, since anytime you pass one you get a reference to the other automatically, which drastically increases coupling.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Please see the update, where I give an example of a usecase

Comment: As one with experience writing circuit simulators: that example is not a good way to do it. It is much more scalable to store components in vectors and use indices, than to throw them all into an ocean of references. It is easier to look up devices by name or type if they are stored in a vector. It is far more cache-friendly, and easier to design a multi-threaded simulator when most data is contiguous. It is far more space-efficient to simply store something at an index, than to put it in a separate allocation and give it a pointer back to its "owner". It's easier to persist to a database...

Comment: @trentcl Maybe you are right, but consider it an educational exercise. I am just trying to understand how such a structure can be created even if there are better ways to implement higher level business logic.

Comment: Sure, I'm not saying this is a bad question. I *am* saying it's a problem you should not encounter very often in well-designed programs. This is true not just in Rust but in any language (the content of my previous comment comes mostly from experience in C++ and Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as others have mentioned, this is likely a bad idea that will not only cause poor performance but will be very difficult to code with. With that warning, on to the answer.

This is a bit tricky because today in stable Rust, you would need to initialize the owner in order to get a reference to it (so you would probably need each field to be `Option<Thing>`; not ideal).

However, as luck would have it, there is an new unstable method [`Rc::new_cyclic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.new_cyclic) which I think does exactly what you want:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3139ef05f5d437bfc0dbf2afa034ffcb)

```rust
#![feature(arc_new_cyclic)]

use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

struct Owner {
    thing1: Thing,
    thing2: Thing,
}

impl Owner {
    fn new() -> Rc<Self> {
        Rc::new_cyclic(|weak| {
            Self {
                thing1: Thing::new(weak.clone()),
                thing2: Thing::new(weak.clone()),
            }
        })
    }
}

struct Thing {
    owner: Weak<Owner>,
    value: u32,
}

impl Thing {
    fn new(owner: Weak<Owner>) -> Self {
        Self {
            owner,
            value: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. So I gather stable simply can't do it? That's surprising. Good to know it will in the future at least.

Comment: Stable can do it, but you would need to initialize the owner before initializing the children, which is the opposite of what we're trying to do. You would either need to do something like `struct Owner { thing1: Option<Thing>, ... }` and initialize to `None`, or if performance is absolutely essential to the point that it is worth unsafe code, you could use `MaybeUninit` then transmute (however, that would technically be UB because we need to make certain assumptions about the internals of `Rc`, which are not *guaranteed* to remain the same in future Rust versions).

Comment: I would either use this unstable method, or if you need a stable version, you can use the safe but moderately inconvenient (and *maybe ever so slightly* inefficient) method of wrapping everything in `Option`.

Comment: Thanks. I considered the "Option" option, but though there should be a way (because why not :) ). Well, as I said it is more of educational exercise to help understand Rust limitations among the other things.

Comment: Glad I could help! This certainly has more value as an exercise (although patterns like this do very occasionally happen in real code, which is why these things exist). Since this kind of thing is somewhat rare, and since IMO Rust is still an evolving language, `Rc::new_cyclic` is just one of many small features that Rust is missing for now, in stable or entirely. I'd imagine that these missing edge cases are one of the main reasons why more people don't use Rust yet. That said, it's definitely already a great language for many many things. And more and more gaps like this are fixed each day.